# Is there a scenario in which the success & error callback function could be called within an ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In below pseudo-code the error a redirect is occurring even though the error callback is being invoked. The success callback should not be called if the error call back is called ?

```
$.ajax({

success : {

redirectPage();
}

error : {

}
```

Comment: An AJAX request can either succeed or fail, it can't do both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the success callback is called, or the error one, but not the both at the same ajax request.

That said, if you need to fake this behavior, here could be a solution:

```
// first solution

$.ajax({
    complete: function() {
        alert("complete() called...");
    }
};

// second solution

function success() {
    alert("success() called...");
}

$.ajax({
    success: success,
    error: function() {
        success();
        // any additional code
    }
};
```

Comment: methinks you're looking for the `complete` callback of `$.ajax`